# resizing the dimensions of the an image field

Tags: media

I need to re-size all the thumbnails of my article images to fit the dimensions of the redesign.

Is there a easy way to do this?

Comment: Are you using D7 or D6?

Comment: I am using Drupal 7.

Comment: i posted the answer for D7 check the below post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you attach an image field to the content type. In that case, you can define the image styles at admin/config/media/image-styles. It is the core continuation of the [Imagecache](http://drupal.org/project/imagecache) module.

Create a new style and set the dimension for the images; then, go to admin/structure/types, click "Manage display" in "Article", and click the icon under format of image field; choose the image style you created.

Comment: Cheers! ill give it a go